# Child UserControl missing datasource when binding through ListView

Tags: asp.net

I have a UserControl that takes a class object as property "DataSource." On DataBind, I apply properties of that object to controls -- TextBox, RadioButton, etc -- inside the UserControl.

This works great when I just set the UC on a page, bind, and go.

Now, I'm attempting to use this control in the **ItemTemplate** of a ListView like so;

`<ItemTemplate><uc1:MyItem ID="MyItem1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem %>' /></ItemTemplate>`

and bind to an array of those objects. The array is populated but I'm reaching my DataBind method of the UC with DataSource = null. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Holidays kept me away from this.

So, apparently I was calling `base.DataBind()` too late. My `LoadForm(DataSource)` method to load the object into the form fields preceded `base.DataBind()`. Swapping them fixed allowed me access to DataSource with no problem.

```
public override void DataBind()
{
  base.DataBind();
  LoadForm(DataSource);
}
```

Am I understanding my problem right? Was I just doing things out of order?

Comment: Have you tried the same thing with a asp:Repeater instead?

Comment: @OrangeKid My guess would be that Container.DataItem is not the right path to your data item.  What are you binding the ListView to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "`<%# %>`" syntax tells the compiler to run the associated code during the control's `DataBinding` event -- but `DataSource` needs to be set before the `DataBinding` event to be effective.

One way to work around the issue might be to do your binding-related processing after the `DataBind` event runs, such as in `PreRender`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to know that you might be reloading the page, and you may try to use the

```
if(!IsPostBack)
```

in your `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`